# How to send pdf generated by TCPDF as Swiftmailer attachment

Tags: php, tcpdf, swiftmailer

I already tried several solutions, the closest (for me) should look like this:

```
$file = $pdf->Output('', 'E');
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($file, 'name.pdf', 'application/pdf'));
```

`$pdf` is an instance of `TCPDF` and `$message` is an instance of `Swift_Message`.
Using above the email is being sent ok, file is attached but when I try to open it I get the error message that file is corrupted or badly encoded.

My question is: how to send pdf generated by TCPDF as Swiftmailer attachment **without saving the file to server and deleting it after sending the email**. [Here](https://tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1) is the link to the TCPDF output method documentation, maybe somebody can see something I have missed.

Answer (score 8):

I am using something like this and it is working. For the PDF content I am using one of the simplest examples on the PDF library.

```
[...]
$pdf_as_string = $pdf->Output('', 'S'); // $pdf is a TCPDF instance
[...]
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance(); // using php mail function
$message->setTo(array(
  "client@customdomain.com" => "Main Email",
  "client@publicdomain.com" => "Secondary Email"
));
$message->setSubject("This email is sent using Swift Mailer");
$message->setBody("You're our best client ever.");
$message->setFrom("developers@mydomain.com", "Developers United");
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_as_string, 'my-file.pdf', 'application/pdf');
$message->attach($attachment);
[...]
```

Maybe this answer comes a little late since I am using swiftmailer v4_3_0 and TCPDF v6_0_002. But just in case is worth to someone.

Comment: This also worked for MPDF. Thanks a lot. Here is a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34785821/386579

Answer (score 4):

I have had no problems attaching TCPDFs on the fly.

I call a function which eventually returns the PDF using the Output type 'S':

`return $pdf->Output('TE_Invoice.pdf', 'S');`

I attach the file using:

```
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance()
  ->setFilename('TE_Invoice.pdf')
  ->setContentType('application/pdf')
  ->setBody($val['file']));
```

Where `$val['file']` is the returned value from above.

I am using TCPDF Version: 5.9.134 and Swift Mailer Version: 4.1.3

Comment: That's how I tried to do it but after I opend pdf in email I get the error message that file is corrupted or badly encoded...

Answer (score 1):

You can use outputmode 'E' to get base64String.

```
$base64PdfString = $pdf->Output('', 'E');
```

**Beware**: Maybe you have to cut the first 5-6 lines, because of

> Content-Type: application/pdf;  name=""
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename=""
>
> Base64StringStartsHere....

cut

```
$base64PdfArray = explode("\r\n", $base64PdfString);
$base64 = '';
for($i = 5; $i < count($base64PdfArray); $i++) {
    $base64 .= $base64PdfArray[$i];
}
```

Now you have the Email as base64String.
Before sending you have to decode it.

```
$mail->attach(new \Swift_Attachment(base64_decode($base64), 'Pdf.pdf', 'application/pdf'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$file = $pdf->Output('', 'S');
```

I'm doing this with another mail backend in `PHP`, and this does work. I guess the mail backend takes care of encoding the attachment, so there is no need to encode it as base64 manually.

Comment: Tried this already, tried again and still doesn't work (same error msg)

Comment: If you save the file to the filesystem, can you open it? If yes, then it is a swiftmailer-fault. Then you at least know where to look further.

Comment: If I save the file and attach it with $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($path)); then everything's ok

Comment: sorry, then i cannot help you. I know nothing about Swiftmailer, I'm using http://pear.php.net/Mail_Mime, and it can successfully add an attachment with `$mime->addAttachment($file, 'application/pdf', 'name.pdf')` generated by `$file = $pdf->Output('', 'S')` ... no big help four you, though.